# Why parameters of my function are appears as boolean values (with JSDocs) whereas is not the case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdoc

I document my reproduction of [tic-tac-toe tutorial](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) of React and I don't understand why parameters of my function are displayed as boolean values (with JSDocs) whereas it is not the case.

This is what appears when I hover the function with cursor :
[View with IntellijSense of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr7xe.png)

Here is the code of my function :

```
/**Return the game board.
 * 
 * @param {boolean} xIsNext Allows to show a text that tell which player is the next.
 * @param {string[]} squares The current board which will be update at the next action.
 * @param {*} onPlay A function that allows to re-render the board.
 * @returns the JSX structure of the board.
 */
function Board({xIsNext, squares, onPlay}) {
  // ...
}
```

Is it the fact that it's in curly braces ? Or it is the presence of React ? Or an another reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Cause the `Board` component takes a single-props argument. Not multi param

It would be best if you defined a type for `BoardProps` like this

```js
/**
 * The board properties.
 * 
 * @typedef {object} BoardProps
 * @property {boolean} xIsNext Allows to show a text that tell which player is the next.
 * @property {string[]} squares The current board which will be update at the next action.
 * @property {*} onPlay A function that allows to re-render the board.
 * /

/**
 * Board component
 * 
 * @param {BoardProps} props The board props
 * @returns {React.ReactElement}
 */
function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worked with your suggestion initially, it was helpful. But now, I share you an another solution (from JSDoc "_documenting a destructuring parameter_") :
`/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
    // ...
};`